# UBUNTU 18.04.01 Autologon effect

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, system-settings

Sound, PulseAudio, Audacious work when autologin is ON, they don't when autologin is OFF.

Any suggestions to remedy this?

I prefer to have autologin OFF. Thanks!

Comment: How do they not work? I think you're misdiagnosing the problem. Once `lightdm` checks for "Autologin Y/N" it should be no different. See `journalctl $(type -p lightdm)`

Comment: When I boot with autologon ON everything works fine. When I boot with autologon OFF it doesn't. I can't even change Output Settings (Output Plugin) of Audacious.